# SQL sum divide by date count

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have table1

```
date        name    item
2021-01-01  Joe      1  
2021-01-01  Joe      1
2020-01-03  Ray      1
2020-01-03  Ray      2
2020-01-03  Ray      3
```

My goal is group by name, date and sum of item divide group count by how many date 
Joe count date =2 divide by 2 ( sum item) 
Ray count date =3 divide by 6 ( sum item)

The outcome like this

```
date        name    item
2021-01-01  Joe      1   
2020-01-03  Ray     .5
```

my query

```
select cast(count(date) as numeric)  / count(item) from table1 group by date
```

the outcome not right

Comment: Please explain how 6 /3 = 0.66?

Comment: Mistaken .Should be count(date)/sum(item)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want the total number of distinct days by the number of occurences for a day-person combination

```
select date, name, (select cast(count(distinct date) as decimal) from table_1) / count(item) from table_1 group by date, name
```

Or if you want the denominator to be some other aggregate of the group (as noted in your comment on the question), just change the `count(item)` to that

Comment: Subqueries are not needed, it can be easier - [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=01d6f2168b1af374134fd861a0d246cd)

Comment: @user14717238 - the expected value for the 2nd row is 0.66, not 0.5

Comment: wait a minutes. Ray suppose divide by 3 days not 2 days. I don't think we can use distinct date.

Comment: @qphan maybe update the question to include the formula for Ray and Joe (eg. Joe = number of rows with Joe and date = 2021-01-01 / blah...)

Comment: I did update my question

Comment: :-) in that case @user14717238's fiddle has the answer you need. You might want to ask him to post that as an answer and accept that instead.

Comment: BTW what you probably want is equivalent to `select date, name, CAST(1 AS decimal) /  avg(item) from table_1 group by date, name`

Comment: Can u explain CAST(1 AS decimal)? I don't understand how you get date  count

Comment: the date count is included in the average. the expression just flips it upside down.

Comment: Nobody knows the correct answer. :-) All attempts in one [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=99c4802188f2fa8f4251097e587d7047)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a single aggregation query:

```
select date, name, count(*) / sum(item)
from t
group by date, name;
```

Or even more simply as:

```
select date, name, 1 / avg(item)
from t
group by date, name;
```